# a good design for threads keep running to monitor if there is pending request

Tags: java, multithreading

I have a thread pool with 10 threads. I want to have this 10 threads keep running to monitor if there is new requests pending. Is this a good design? If yes, how can I make them keep running? Cause right now, they done the work once and then end. If no, what is a better design? Any way we have one thread keep doing the job and 2nd one go alive when there are one more requests become pending? Thanks

Comment: You should use a Blocking Queue data structure to do this. I would suggest you read this article once http://tutorials.jenkov.com/java-concurrency/thread-pools.html

Comment: as mentioned in other comment you can implement your thread pool and use blocking queue to enque and dequeue the requests. The second option is using Executor framework. you can create a ExecutorService by using Executors utility methods and then can subit the requests. ExecutorService will manage the threadpool for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is this a good design?

Basically, no.

It is never good design to reimplement functionality that is provided by classes in Java SE standard class library.

In this case, you should be using an `ExecutorService` implementation with a bounded threadpool.  It may also be advisable to use a bounded work queue to avoid problems if the request rate could exceed your system's ability to process them.

(If your request queue is unbounded or if the bound is too large, you can end up with problems like the requestor timing out before your system starts processing the request.  If your system can't detect that, then it *wastes* resources on processing requests whose responses won't be used.  A bounded queue with a relatively small bound ... or even a `SynchronousQueue` ... is advisable if you need to cope gracefully with overload.)

Comment: This is going to be a async procdure. Our design is to write the request to the db table and our threads will go there to pick it up. From your point of view, anything wrong with this design? Will the 10 threads (we use executorservice and set the pool size to 10) keep monitoring the db table a good idea? Thanks.

Comment: Well that is a different problem to the one you previously described.  Are you using the database table as a persistent queue?  If yes, then you could use one thread to read requests from the database, and then submit them as tasks for processing by the pool managed by the ExecutorService.  However, a better idea would be to use an off-the-shelf queuing system; e.g. JMS.  Once again, you should avoid reimplementing the wheel.  Use an existing solution.

Comment: When u said queuing system, you mean instead of using database, I should use a queuing sys. e.g. JMS, activemq. Right?

Comment: Well ... if that is what you are effectively using the database table for ... basically yes.  However, since you haven't given a proper coherent description of what you are doing, it is not clear that this kind of piecemeal advice is sound.  Maybe you would be better off paying a consultant to advise you on this.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Stephen. Your advice helps a lot.

Answer (score 2):

Threads run() should be running in a loop, something like this:

```
class Executor extends Thread {
    Runnable task;

    public void run() {
        for (;;) {
            task.run();
            synchronized (this) {
                try {
                    wait();
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

queue based version:

```
public void run() {
    for (;;) {
        try {
            Runnable task = queue.take();
            task.run();
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        }
    }
}
```